# BrowserBear select dynamic element by id

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm using BrowserBear to submit an online form.  The online form has dynamic elements allowing you to add more than one contact method.  The contact method consists of two elements - Select box and text field.

The dropdown box allows you to select the contact method (i.e. email, phone etc).
The text field allows you to enter the contact information (i.e. test@email.com, 07755566677).

The form allows you to add multiple contact methods.  However, when a new contact method is added, the ID number assigned to the fields is dynamically created and changes on each page load.

For example:

```
contact_form[details][1707633231268][label]
```

BrowserBear uses XPath to select the elements in the form, but my question is how do I select the dynamic select form by ID?

Below is the code that the helper creates, however it doesn't allow for a dynamic field.

```
{"xpath":"/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/section/form/div[5]/div[3]/div[1]/label/select","element":"<select class=\"frm__input frm__input--short\" name=\"contact_form[details][1707633231268][label]\" id=\"contact_form_details_1707633231268_label\"><option value=\"Email\">Email</option><option value=\"Email invoices to\">Email invoices to</option><option value=\"Home\">Home</option><option value=\"Mobile\">Mobile</option><option value=\"Office\">Office</option><option value=\"Work\">Work</option><option value=\"Other...\">Other...</option></select>"}
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share the url?

Comment: if it's a dynamic ID, then you can't use the id to create your selector.   You might choose a more path-based approach.  The user has some way to find things.  You might ask yourself when viewing the page, "how do I locate these fields?".  Then translate that into a locator.  So maybe when you add a form, it creates a label/title of "Contact 2", "Contact 3", etc... hopefully it gives more input to the user than that, but once you find those cues, you can traverse the DOM from there.